# How to include msoFileDialogFolderPicker in a userform

Tags: vba, userform

In a vba userform I'm prompting the user with several questions.  I'm stuck with one particular prompt.  I'm don't know how to include a prompt for an msoFileDialogFolderPicker within a userform.
I've used code similar to the function outlined below as an individual popup, but I don't know how to place this inside a userform.  Is this possible?

```
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a module (in VBA window, left pane, right click, Insert..., Module). Then move your function `GetFolder()` in this module, declared as `public`

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Then in your form, you want something that will call the procedure. Usually we do that with a button.

So, add a button to the form. Then double-click on the button (or right-click and "code") and it will create a click event for it.

In the button event code, call your `GetFolder` procedure:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim strFolder As String

    strFolder = GetFolder()

    MsgBox strFolder

End Sub
```